# Mongodb: Is it possible to turn off authentication for connections from localhost only?

Tags: mongodb

Here is my scenario - I have a webapp and mongodb running on same host. And I have not enabled authorization in mongod.conf. So, my webapp, connects to mongodb with out any authentication. Now I want to provide access to mongodb for certain group of people who will connect from outside. Since, connections will be made from outside, I need to enable authentication. But, if I enable authentication webapp will not be able to connect to mongodb(which assumes mongodb is running on localhost and it does not require authentication). I do not want to change webapp to connect to mongodb with authentication. So, I want to disable authentication only for connections from localhost. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible from Mongo 3.0 version
The only case where localhost authentication bypass occurs is when there are no configured users, with [`enableLocalhostAuthBypass`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.enableLocalhostAuthBypass) parameter (Enabled by default).
Your scenario can only be solved by creating multiple roles / users with different privileges